# How to register Mongo client from extension method

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to register a MongoDB using [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

But after moving my service registration to an extensin method, I can't seem to pass my options to `Configure` method:

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddMongoRepo(
    _configuration.GetOptions<MongoConfig>("MongoConfig"));
```

**ServiceCollectionExtensions**

```
public static void AddMongoRepo(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    MongoConfig configuration)
{
    services.Configure<MongoConfig>(configuration);

    services.AddSingleton<MongoConfig>(sp =>
        sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MongoConfig>>().Value);
}
```

When trying to call `Configure` it moans that

> cannot convert from MongoConfig to System.Action

I can call `Configure` from startup directly, but I would rather keep all of this logic in my Dependency Injection area for the Mongo repo.

If I try passing `IConfigurationSection` to the extension method, it keeps trying to use the wrong overload for `Configure`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you try changing the `GetOptions` to `GetSection`? e.g. `services.Configure<MongoConfig>(_configuration.GetSection("MongoConfig"));`

Comment: @Skami Turns out the projects had mismatched versions of `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` so just a bunch of missing overloads

Comment: That makes a lot more sense :)